# Strange spare single quotes before listings environment

Tags: listings

I have a problem when trying to show a console output in my document with the package `lstlisting`. It shows a spare single quotes, as seen in the first line of the below picture:

[image]

This code reproduces the problem (at least for me). I'd like help to get rid of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
        backgroundcolor=\color{white},
        basicstyle={\footnotesize\color{black},\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont,\bfseries},
        stringstyle=\color{black},
        breakatwhitespace=false,
        breaklines=true,
        captionpos=b,
        keepspaces=true,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        showtabs=false,
        tabsize=2,
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
\lstset{escapeinside={<@}{@>}}
\begin{lstlisting}
traceroute to upm.es (138.100.200.6), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  1.600 ms  3.262 ms  3.260 ms
2  10.233.128.1 (10.233.128.1) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  8.496 ms  13.889 ms  13.911 ms
3  10.239.240.113 (10.239.240.113) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  13.945 ms  14.828 ms  17.957 ms
4  10.254.14.1 (10.254.14.1) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  27.655 ms  28.202 ms  29.326 ms
5  10.239.240.181 (10.239.240.181) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  32.501 ms 10.254.13.201 (10.254.13.201) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  33.297 ms  33.321 ms
6  10.254.13.237 (10.254.13.237) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  29.209 ms 10.254.2.137 (10.254.2.137) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  19.383 ms 10.254.2.145 (10.254.2.145) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  17.886 ms
7  10.254.3.226 (10.254.3.226) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  20.164 ms  17.590 ms 10.254.14.106 (10.254.14.106) <@\textcolor{red}{[*]}@>  54.655 ms
8  rediris.baja.espanix.net (193.149.1.26) <@\textcolor{green}{[AS6895]}@>  22.132 ms  22.362 ms rediris.alta.espanix.net (193.149.1.154) <@\textcolor{green}{[AS6895]}@>  22.240 ms
9  redimadrid-cieamt-router.rediris.es (130.206.212.106) <@\textcolor{blue}{[AS766]}@>  18.079 ms  21.496 ms *
10  * upm-ciemat.net.redimadrid.es (193.145.14.133) <@\textcolor{blue}{[AS766]}@>  55.954 ms *
11  www.upm.es (138.100.200.6) <@\textcolor{blue}{[AS766]}@>  20.736 ms  20.866 ms  19.413 ms\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're commas, actually. The culprit is

```
basicstyle={\footnotesize\color{black},\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont,\bfseries},
```

which should be

```
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
```

You have to combine all font declaration, not give a list of declarations.

Note that `\bfseries` will do nothing with family `cmtt` that has no boldface. Also `\color{black}` seems redundant.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, nice and easy. Thank you for the additional explanation.